# Query to extract only records which have failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I need a help in writing a SQL for the below table. I have a table with two columns (Name and Status).

```
Name    Status
Kevin   success 
Mark    fail 
Mark    success 
Mike    success 
Yann    fail 
Yann    success 
George  fail
Boi     Fail
```

From the above table, I would like to extract only records which have failed and also which are failed then succeeded. Basically I would like to exclude the records which are just succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I would like to exclude the records which are just succeeded.

If you want all records whose `name` has at least one non-`'success'` status, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists(
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.status <> 'success'
)
```

Alternatively, if you want a list of `name`s that have at least one non-`'success'` status, then you can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select name
from mytable
group by name
having max(case when status <> 'success' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is using `WITH TIES`

Not clear if you want ALL records or just distinct Names

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(50),[Status] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Kevin','success')
,('Mark','fail')
,('Mark','success')
,('Mike','success')
,('Yann','fail')
,('Yann','success')
,('George','fail')
,('Boi','Fail')

Select top 1 with ties *
 From @YourTable
 Order By min(case when status='Fail' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by [Name] )
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Status
Boi     Fail
George  fail
Mark    fail
Mark    success
Yann    fail
Yann    success
```

**Kevin and Mike are excluded**